# Как удалить 'команду' из строки?

Tags: python

Проблема заключается в том, что я хочу сделать что бы пользователь вводил команда + какой-то текст, а программа выводила этот текст. Например

```
commands = ['/add', '/del']
action = input('Ввод: ')
```

И при условии если пользователь введет к примеру такое значение

```
/add  *какой-то текст*
```

То я получу только значение

```
*какой-то текст*
```

Я перерыл весь интернет, для решентя этой проблемы. Пробовал через str.translate(). Проблема в том что я даже не знаю как можно загуглить данный вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
commands = ['/add', '/del']

action = '/add  *какой-то текст*' # input('Ввод: ')

cmd, *rest = action.strip().split()

if cmd in commands:
    print('Command:', cmd)
    print('Action:', ' '.join(rest))
```

`.split()` разбивает строку на массив строк, разделитель - пробел.

`cmd, *rest = ['/add', '*какой-то', 'текст*']`

В переменную `cmd` попадает первый элемент, в `rest` - все остальные, в виде массива.